# How to reduce space between button text when new line is inserted in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button with a new line inserted to break the long text of button in different lines . But there is a huge amount of space between the texts which is unwanted , i am not able to reduce the space by any means .

```
 <button mat-stroked-button>New <br /> Send</button>
 <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">Submit/<br />Now</button>
```

Can anyone help me in how to reduce the space between the 2 lines ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need "override" the line-heigth, e.g.

```
.mat-stroked-button{
  line-height:1.25rem;
}
```

If you only want to affect one button define a class like

```
.mat-stroked-button.custom{
  line-height:1.25rem;
}
```

And use

```
<button mat-stroked-button class="custom">..</button>
```

NOTE: I use only with mat-stroked-button, see the .css that is created with the differents buttons and extend the idea